# Angularjs passing id into modal function()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am using angularjs and spring mvc for my application. At first I am displaying all the placements with one button Placed Candidates. I am doing `ng-repeat` for displaying all the placements.

Here is my html.

```
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="placement in placements">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <h5>{{placement.companyName}}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <h6>{{placement.placementDate | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</h6>
        Company Target (appox):10 Achieved: 
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-ng-
    click="placedcandidatespopup(placement.placementId);">//here i can
    get particular placementId but how to pass this id to 
    savePlacementStudents() method in controller.js???//
    PlacedCandidates
      </a>
    </div>
```

I am calling one modal popup function. Here is controller.js

```
    $scope.placedcandidatespopup = function()
    {
    AdminUsersService.getAllUsers().then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.allusers=response.data;
        console.log($scope.allusers);
    })
    $(".placedcandidates").modal("show");
    }
```

I am calling modal by name "placedcandidates".

Here is the modal

```
    <div class="modal right fade placedcandidates" id="myModal1"
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" data-ng-
    repeat="student in allusers">
    <input id="{{student.studentId}}" type="checkbox" value="
    {{student.studentId}}" data-ng-
    checked="selection.indexOf(student.studentId) >-1" 
    data-ng-click="toggleSelection(student.studentId)"/> 
    <label for="{{student.studentId}}"></label>
    {{student.firstName}}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="position: fixed;">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn" data-ng-
    click="savePlacementStudents()">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

After clicking on button popup modal will display with all Students with checkboxes placed beside them.Now I am able to save studentId into database.But I am not able to pass `placementId` for saving.

Here is my `savePlacementStudents` method in controller.js.

```
    $scope.selectedStudents = {};
    $scope.savePlacementStudents = function(selectedStudents)
    {
    selectedStudents.selectedList = $scope.selection;
    AdminPlacementService.savePlacementStudents(selectedStudents).then
    (function(response)
    {
                if(response.data=="success"){       
                $window.scrollTo(0,0);
                $scope.selectedStudents = {};
                $scope.getplacementdetails($scope.currentPageIndex);
                $scope.successmessage="Student Selection Saved!;
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.successmessage="";
                    $scope.closeplacedcandidatespopup();
                    }, 1500);
                        }
                });
    }
```

Can anyone tell how can I pass respective `placementId` to this `saveStudents method()` so that I can set that `placementId` for those students selected.

Comment: Don't use jQuery to open the model. Inject the ui-bootstrap modal and use that the angularjs way https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

The `placementId` passed to function `placedcandidatespopup` can be saved as follows in function `placedcandidatespopup`

```
$scope.selectedPlacementId = placementId;
```

Now the same `$scope` will have access in Popup also as it is using same `controller.js`. And now you can use this `$scope.selectedPlacementId` anywhere in `controller.js` 
So you don't need to pass `placementId`...!!

Hope that would help you..!!

Comment: Hi.If i use user.userId it will give me StudentId.But i need to get placementId for saving.Upto modal i can get but how to get it for saving?

Comment: @Sachin HR..  Updated my answer..!!

Comment: selectedStudents.placementId = $scope.selectedPlacementId. Can i use like this in savePlacementStudents() method?

Comment: Yes. You can use it as long as you have `savePlacementStudents` method in same `controller.js`.

Comment: I don't think you can send `selectedStudents` object like this in query parameters. You need to convert it to JSON string with `JSON.stringify(jsonObj)` and that is not good way to send data at all. Instead I would suggest you to send data in body of request, not in URL.

Comment: selectedStudents.placementId = $scope.selectedPlacementId.I used this approach only and I sent only selectedStudents object and placementId is getting saved.Thank you very much. Its working now

Comment: Yea i have upvoted ur answer and i have accepted too.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.placedcandidatespopup = function(id)
    {
        AdminUsersService.getAllUsers().then(function(response)
        {
           $scope.allusers=response.data;
           console.log($scope.allusers);
        })


        $scope.inserted = {
                            placementId:id,
                        };

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({

                            templateUrl: 'views/test/myModal1.html',
                            controller: 'TestCntrl',
                            size: "Modelwidth",
                            resolve: {
                                items: function () {
                                    return $scope.inserted;
                                }
                            }
           });

}
```

In model you have to access using `items.placementId` and when you `savePlacementStudents()` method send placementId as well with student info.

Comment: Yea thank you for suggesting.Its working.I just passed id from placedcandidatedpopup to saveStudents method()